# Geometrically accurate way of creating a venn diagram

Tags: adobe-indesign, shapes, alignment, information-graphics, diagram

I am looking for a geometrically accurate way of creating a venn diagram.

Lacking a specific method, I improvised and the circles probably don't overlap like they should. So when I replicate one group 3 times, I get this shape overlap, probably because of the inaccuracy of my method aligning the original circles to each other.

What's a geometric way to build this, preferably in InDesign? thanks

In my image below, I first created the bottom circle, then cut out the dotted section and created a group. I replicated that group twice and kind of manually positioned them to look like a venn, but this resulted in having that highlighted overlap.

[image]

Comment: How about drawing a circle, rotating it twice by 120 degrees, with an offset pivot? Don’t have my Illustrator at hand to further clarify the steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Illustrator...

- Draw a circle and note the **diameter**.
  For the purposes of initial construction using a round integer for the diameter is helpful. Here, I've used a circle of 210pts in diameter. One can *always* scale or rotate the final result, *after* the basic figures are constructed.
- Select the circle and choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Transform`
- Tick `Preview`
- Enter **120°** into the `Angle` field (360°/ 3 = 120°)
- In the `Move > Horizontal` field insert a *negative*, evenly divisible value based upon the circle's diameter. So, I enter 105pts (210 / 2 = 105) Ideally, one would use something like 50%, but relative values aren't viable in these fields for some reason. (At least in the version of AI I'm using)
- For the `9-Point Origin` box click *any **side** point*. (Note the Move > Horizontal values I've used here are related to the center right origin being selected. Other origins will require *different* settings.)
- Insert **2** for the `Copies` field.
- Click `OK`

[image]

`Object > Expand Appearance` will result in a *group* of 3 individual circles and "bake in" the effect.

---

For me personally, who *always* has Illustrator available, I'd create this in Illustrator, Expand the Appearance, then copy/paste into Indesign. Using the Effect in Illustrator allows one to more easily control the offsets.

For example in Illustrator, if you want *less* of an inset you can just reduce the `Move > Horizontal` amount:

[image]

<sub>(210pt diameter / 6 = 35pts)</sub>

---

### Indesign...

Not where I'd normally do this, but it can be done with a few more steps. There may be a couple *different* ways to accomplish this.

A slightly complex method...

This method creates the 3 circles so they align on middle points and are all 3 evenly divided, similar to the first image in the Illustrator method above.

First, make certain the `9-point Origin` on the **Transform Panel** is set to center right.

[image]

- Draw an even diameter circle (I used 210pts again)
- Choose `Object > Transform > Rotate...`
- Enter **180°** and hit **`Copy`**

[image]

- Select the original circle again
- Choose `Object > Transform > Rotate...`
- Enter **120°** and hit **`Copy`**

[image]

This should result in the 3 circles. Essentially you rotate the original circle by half a full rotation making a copy to get circle 2. Then rotate the original circle a second time by 1/3 of a full rotation making a copy to get circle 3. 
<sub>1 first circle (original 360° / 1 = no change), 2nd circle (360°/ 2 = 180°), then 3rd circle (360° / 3 = 120°).</sub>

Select *both* the rotated circles...

- Choose `Object > Transform > Move...`
- Enter an evenly divisible, *negative* integer into the `Horizontal` Field 
   210pts / 2 = 105pts. So I enter -105pts to move the circles left half the diameter.
- Click `OK`

[image]

<sub>(I did choose `Object > Transform > Clear Transformations` to reset Indesign bounding boxes at this point.)</sub>

[image]

Because of how InDesign transformations are all relative to each individual object, if one wants a Venn Diagram that is *not* a 50% division of the circles, offsets and rotation angles will *all* change and need to be recalculated. It's simply not as easy to adjust in Indesign.

---

Comment: Such an elaborate answer Scott, yes.. I was aware AI would be easier for this. Sorry for adding my ID remark, which literally expanded your answer. thank you

Comment: If it was just you and I posting @Lucian I'd have been much more brief, since I know you have strong kung fu. `:)` It's only more elaborate for random Google drop ins that aren't as knowledgable as yourself.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdX7j.png mission accomplished

Comment: Nicely done! ! !